# Centre align a div with images and links as contents

Tags: css

i've been facing trouble with aligning some content  to center of a page... the point is, i was able to achieve it .. but when the browser is resized, the content on the left side is not visible.. i am not sure where i am going wrong.. the code is as follows...

HTML Code ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Home</title>
<link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<img class="logo" src="logo.jpg" width="160px" height="83px">

<div id="menualign">
 <ul>
    <li class="topli"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="topli"><a href="" target="_blank">site 1</a></li>
    <li class="topli"><a href="" target="_blank">Site 2</a></li>
    <li class="topli"><a href="">Logout</a></li>
 </ul>

</div>
<img src="bgn.jpg" width="900" height="7" id="bar">

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code is as follows

```
#container
{

 width:920px;
 height:600px;    
 position:absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-left: -460px;
 margin-top: -300px;
}

#menualign
{
position:relative;
left:24%;
}

#menualign ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}
#menualign ul li { display: inline; }

#menualign ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 16px;
padding: .2em 1.41em;
color: #0056A2;
background-color: #fed352;
}

img.logo
{
position:relative;
top:20px;
}

#menualign ul li a:hover
{
color:black;
font-size:17px;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to align your menu with the the image to the left ?

Comment: yeah...  the idea is to align the logo to left most corner of the div,then the menu items come to right most corner with the third image as a line which underlines both the above contents ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position your container with `margin:0 auto;` and then give `float:left` to the image and `float:right` to the menu. Last give menu `line-height` of the image height to align it verticaly.

```
#container
{
 width:920px; 
 margin:0 auto;
}
#menualign ul li {
 margin-top:10px;
 line-height:83px; 
  float:left;
}
img.logo
{
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
}
```

Ok i made a little jsFiddle and I hope it will help.[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNwsV/1/)

Comment: beautiful ... works perfectly all right.. a little more help... the menu is a little over the top of the second image... i need it a bit down.. so i tried using top:20px; in both #menualign ul and #menualign ul  .. but doesn't help... if i change the line-height .. the entire block is moving down .. how to tackle this.. and one more thing.. in my previous code .. all the menu items were separated with a white space between each <li> .. now all of them are coming one beside the other.....

Comment: i edited just give `menualign ul li` a `margin-top:10px` and `border-right:1px solid white` or just add `margin-right;5px` to add `5px` space between menu items

Comment: thanks a lot ...and with margin-right:7px;
 in `menualign ul li ` i get the items separated  by a white space :)                                                                                                                                                   cool... i tried the same thing... :)